# Facebook ID integers being returned oddly

Tags: facebook-fql, json

I'm making FQL calls using the following url and then making a curl call.

$url = 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token='.$access_token.'&query='.rawurlencode($query).'&format=JSON';

and I then pass the returned data through a json_decode call

I've got this query:

SELECT name,page_id,page_url FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid= $uid )

which returns a list of the names and pages for which the specified UID is an administrator.

On some PHP installs (and I've not been able to narrow it down) the page_id is turned from a long integer into a scientific notation - so 174311849258492 is returned as 1.7431184925849E 14  which of course breaks things.

As I can't reproduce this on my server I'm not sure where the conversion is happening. Digging around I've found a suggestion that doing this:

json_decode( preg_replace('/:(\d+,)/', ':"${1}",', $response ) );

will fix it

But why do some json_decodes cast into scientific notation for no apparent reason?

Comment: The problem lies in 32bit vs 64bit servers. The largest 32bit unsigned int is 2147483647. Using the regex you have will fix the issue.

Comment: It seems to shove a comma on the end now - but I guess I can always strip that off when I'm processing. So basically anyone running any php code against Facebook who is on a 32 bit server is going to have this problem...  yuk!

Comment: You have an extra comma after d+. Try this one preg_replace('/"id":(\d+)/', '"id":"$1"', $jsonString)

Comment: Sorry, did a little more research. There is a fourth parameter to json_decode that converts big integers to strings. json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING).

Comment: Nope - that one just makes it go back to how it was before. The problem with that parameter is that its only valid from php 5.3 so if you try to use it on anything less you get "PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects at most 2 parameters, 4 given "

Comment: However moving the id so that its the last field seems to fix it.

Why didn't FB store those IDs as strings....

Comment: I got it working by doing :

`$response=preg_replace('/"gid":(\d+)/', '"gid":"$1"', $response );
 $x=json_decode( preg_replace('/"page_id":(\d+)/', '"page_id":"$1"', $response ) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Danny pointed out its a 32/64 bit issue. FB assume that everything is 64 bit and pass back an integer for this value rather than a string.

So what you need to do is take the integers and convert them to strings BEFORE pulling them from the JSON array. Page IDs and Group IDs are passed as integers (Facebook user IDs are passed as strings)

The code to do this is:

```
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $err_no=curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response=preg_replace('/"gid":(\d+)/', '"gid":"$1"', $response );
    $response=json_decode( preg_replace('/"page_id":(\d+)/', '"page_id":"$1"', $response ) );
    if (isset($response->message)) { 
        throw new Exception ($response->message);
    }
    return( $response);
```

Comment: I've the similar issue, and i'm using graph API which returns array and not a json data... Did you added your own curl.. I could not understand what should replace the $ch in the first line.. I've raised a question in Stackoverflow at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667437/how-to-handle-the-big-int-facebook-uid-returned-by-fql

Comment: I moved to making my own API interface as I only needed a fraction of the functionality of the full PHP SDK and that why I can customise things as and how I want.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using your own curl calls then you can simply append &format=JSON-STRINGS onto the end of the url which returns all items as strings.

Comment: Just an FYI for people who see this... it appears that facebook now interprets this parameter with case sensitiviy and the parameter needs to be `&format=json-strings`