# Decoding json in php and facebook api

Tags: php, json, facebook

I am a bit new to json. I get this below response from facebook oauth. And i am unable to get a proper way to get the data into variable/object in php.

```
{
   "data":{"app_id":xxxxxxxxxx,
           "is_valid":true,
           "application":"Opensource Education Dot in",
           "user_id":xxxxxxxxxx,
           "issued_at":1389448259,
           "expires_at":1394632259,
           "scopes":["basic_info","email","public_profile","user_friends"]
          }

}
```

This where i am stuck. Dont know how to get each response. Also I only get this as response. But the exact values in the scope(like email, basic_info etc.) how do i get them?

```
$userdata=json_decode($response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$userdata=json_decode($response,true);
```

For the long userids issue you can use the below -

```
$userdata= = json_decode(preg_replace('/"uid":(\d+)/', '"uid":"$1"', $response),true);
```

Also Could be used as

```
$userdata=  json_decode($response, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)
```

It will give you an array.

In addition you can check the thread for more variations

[How to get around or make PHP json_decode not alter my very large integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759314/how-to-get-around-or-make-php-json-decode-not-alter-my-very-large-integer-values)

Comment: HI, the app id and userid are too long so getting it in exponential form. How do i solve this?

Comment: I have updated the  answer check now.. you can replace the uid in the preg_replace with yours, I think its user_id in your case.

Comment: You can check here for similar long userid issue answered by me before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931751/fql-api-issues-with-array-translation/20931887#20931887

Comment: I have two data that are long. app_id and user_id. So user_id is working fine. But 4 parameters were not accepted in the above format.
So what about app_id

Comment: Then use json_decode($response, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING); this will covert all the big ints to string. Let me update the answer.