# Smartsheet API returns weird/truncated row ID on row insert?

Tags: smartsheet-api

My PHP script is using the `Smartsheet` API to insert new rows into a sheet.

What I am getting back for row ID doesn't look numeric, and I can't use it for any subsequent lookups:

```
[id] => 7.4588918092066E+14
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're running a 32-bit version of PHP, which has a hard time interpreting the Long Ids returned by the Smartsheet API. When the Long rowIds come in precision is lost, and the rowId is returned in scientific notation.

To get around this truncation convert the rowId value to a string before parsing the json response to PHP.

This other answer from a post regarding Ids returned by the facebook API https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019715/413234 explains a similar situation and how to use `preg_replace` to grab the id and convert it to a string, before passing it to `json_decode()`.

Comment: The other option is to move to a 64-bit version of PHP, if at all possible.